# Eigenvectors Operators and Unilateral Shifts

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

We showed that a (non-zero) compact self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space always has an eigenvector.  Let $V:l^2(\mathbb{N})\to l^2(\mathbb{N})$ be the *unilateral shift*, the unique bounded operator on $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ that satisfies
$$
V\delta_n=\delta_{n+1}
$$
for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (here $\delta_n$ is the element of the standard orthonormal basis of $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ defined by 
$$
\delta_n(m)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & m=n \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.
$$

I . Let $f(n)=1/n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (assume $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,...\}$ for this problem).  Show that $M_fV$ is compact and has no eigenvectors.

II. Let $g(x)=x$, and let $M_g:L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$ be the associated multiplication operator.  Show that $M_g$ is self-adjoint and has no eigenvectors.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? For 1, if $x$ were an eigenvector, what must the $1$ component of $x$ look like? What does this mean for the $2$ component? For compactness ignore $V$ at first, can you think of a finite rank approximation of $M_f$? For 2, on $[0,1]$ you have $x<1$ almost everywhere, what happens to scalar products $\langle x f, g \rangle$?

Comment: @s.harp I assume that for 2 you are hinting at some type of self-adjointness in $M_g$ but I don't yet see....

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\|M_{f}Vx\| \le \frac{1}{2}\|x\|$, $\|(M_fV)(M_fV)x\|\le \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}\|x\|$. By induction,
$$
          \|(M_{f}V)^{k}x\| \le \frac{1}{(k+1)!}\|x\|,\;\;\; k=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
Therefore, if $M_fV x = \lambda x$ for some $\lambda$,
$$
                      |\lambda|^k\|x\|=\|(M_{f}V)^{k}Vx\| \le \frac{1}{(k+1)!}\|x\|,\\
            \|x\| \le \frac{|\lambda|^{-k}}{(k+1)!}\|x\|.
$$
The right side of the last inequality tends to $0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$ because $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{|\lambda|^{-k}}{k!} =e^{1/|\lambda|}$ converges. So $M_fV$ has no non-zero eigenvectors for any $\lambda \ne 0$. And $\mathcal{N}(M_{f}V)=\{0\}$ is easily verified. So $M_{f}V$ has no eigenvalues. If $P_{k}x$ is the projection onto the first $k$ components of $x$, then
$$
             \|M_{f}VP_{k}-M_{f}V\| \le \frac{1}{k}.
$$
So $M_{f}V$ is the norm limit of a sequence of finite-rank operators.

Comment: What does your notation $\mathcal{N}(M_fV)=\{0\}$ mean?

Comment: $\mathcal{N}$=null space. You're welcome.

Comment: As to II, we have, if $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue with eigenfunction $f$,

\begin{equation*}
\parallel (x-\lambda )f\parallel ^{2}=\int_{0}^{1}dx(x-\lambda
)^{2}|f(x)|^{2}=0
\end{equation*}
But then $f(x)$ must vanish a.e. and we have a contradiction.

Comment: @Urgje : Thank you. I forgot about that part.